# How can I stop audio from causing a hard lockup?

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, crash, lockup

This is actually a half-continuation of an [old thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605892/daily-ubuntu-freezes-following-certain-behaviour), as I'm getting a very similar problem having fixed the last one for a few weeks, but I was recommended this site as a more relevant place to ask the question and I don't know what the guidelines are for reopening threads in any case.

At this point, I'm 90% sure that my crashes are each being caused by an audio (/audio driver) problem. Around once or twice a day (or every few hours), my **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** system becomes completely unresponsive (REISUB has never once worked with this particular type of crash). It doesn't occur while I'm doing anything significant such as compiling some code, or even with many applications open, but it always happens when I'm playing some audio - for example, while a YouTube video's on (I have one in the background for a few hours each day) or when I test some music in LMMS.
After it occurs (always without warning), the screen display freezes and the system stops responding, but the audio played over the last half second or so is repeated endlessly until I have to resort to cold rebooting.

Does anyone have any idea of what this could be caused by, or something I could do to find out? I've already checked journalctl for every time it's happened and I can't see any patterns in the moments before the lockup.

Thanks in advance, Dominic

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know this isn't exactly as an answer as I still don't know what caused my problem, but it doesn't seem right to simply put this in a comment either as it's quite significant.

A few days after posting this question - after over a week of Ubuntu hard-locking at least once a day - the crashing suddenly stopped, and as of posting this it hasn't happened at all for 7 days (I kept a close record) although I haven't changed my usage of the system or audio. I'm guessing that something broken fixed itself, an overflowing data cache got refreshed, or part of the system was updated resulting in a much lower frequency of audio-related problems.

If someone thinks they know what was going on, please do post an answer as I'll still be checking back on this every so often. In the meantime, I'll wait for a while longer before posting an update on the situation (e.g. whether I start getting crashes again or not).